# Inserting a Page Break in a Word Document Before a Bookmark using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

How would you go about inserting a page break in a word document before a bookmark? 
I tried the following code but had no luck, if anyone has any ideas I'd love to hear them.

```
Set wRng = wdDoc.Bookmarks(FundCommentary).Range
    wRng.HomeKey wdLine, wdMove
    wRng.MoveUp wdLine, 1
    wRng.InsertBreak wdPageBreak
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Set wRng = wdDoc.Bookmarks(FundCommentary).Range
wRng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
wRng.InsertBreak wdPageBreak
```

Comment: Hey Tim, thank you for the response. When I place this snippet in my code for the existing approach, it gives me an error saying the document isn't open? Any suggestions?

Comment: I used `ActiveDocument` in my testing, and did not change to match your posted code using `wdDoc`: fixed that now, so see if it works.  Do you have Word added as a reference, or are you using late binding?  A bit more of your code plus an explanation of what "had no luck" actually looks like would be useful.

Comment: I used Set wRng = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("FundCommentary").Range and it worked, thank you once again!